# What is HttpRequestMessage.Properties?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

What is the purpose of [**HttpRequestMessage.Properties**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties.aspx)?

I'm wondering if it provides something useful for my application.

Answer (score 6):

In Web Api it contains some special flags: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/asp-net-web-api-2-and-httprequestcontext/

For example, IncludeErrorDetail, IsLocal, ClientCertificate are stored in the dictionary, but have properties for easy access.

Comment: Apart from the high level description, how are they placed in the HTTP request? As headers? In the body?

Comment: I would also be interested to understand where and how these properties are stored in the request. In particular because the dictionary values are of type `Object`, so are they serialized? To Json, to something else?

Answer (score 3):

I found this statement from [THOMAS LEVESQUE'S .NET BLOG](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/) which is how I was hoping to use it. MS or other places don't really describe it correctly... that we can use it however we want to carry per request information.  In my case, store information about the destination so that I can validate the certificate per destination.

> Let's see how we can associate a timeout value to a request. The
>   HttpRequestMessage class has a Properties property, which is a
>   dictionary in which we can put whatever we need. We're going to use
>   this to store the timeout for a request, and to make things easier,
>   we'll create extension methods to access the value in a strongly-typed
>   fashion: